# Filtering logs sent by opentelemetry-agent to Coralogix

Tags: kubernetes, metrics

I'm trying to figure out how to configure this [filterprocessor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/filterprocessor/README.md) to filter some kind of logs.

I've created for myself playground in minikube with app that randomly generates logs and installed otel integration to [coralogix](https://coralogix.com/docs/set-up-kubernetes-observability-using-opentelemetry-advanced-configuration/).

The example of logs:

```json
{
    "level": "error",
    "ts": 1709652353.609003,
    "caller": "logs-generator/logs-generator.go:60",
    "msg": "Each Set Am.",
    "error": "expected header is undefined",
    "stacktrace": "anatoly.dev/dummy-logs/internal/logs-generator.(*LogsGenerator).GenerateRandomErrorLog\n\t/app/internal/logs-generator/logs-generator.go:60\nanatoly.dev/dummy-logs/internal/logs-generator.(*LogsGenerator).GenerateRandomLog\n\t/app/internal/logs-generator/logs-generator.go:71\nanatoly.dev/dummy-logs/cmd.NewRootCommand.NewStartCommand.func1\n\t/app/cmd/start.go:38\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute\n\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:983\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC\n\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1115\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute\n\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1039\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteContext\n\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1032\nmain.main\n\t/app/main.go:14\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:271"
  },
  {
    "level": "warn",
    "ts": 1709652354.6102042,
    "caller": "logs-generator/logs-generator.go:47",
    "msg": "The SMS circuit is down, construct the redundant monitor so we can synthesize the EXE sensor!",
    "name": "Silas Anderson",
    "email": "lonnyernser@wiegand.biz",
    "phone": "8381490753",
    "color": "White"
  },
{
    "level": "info",
    "ts": 1709652350.6055088,
    "caller": "logs-generator/logs-generator.go:47",
    "msg": "The SSL array is down, deconstruct the online protocol so we can load the AI interface!",
    "name": "George Rice",
    "email": "winonagrimes@kuhic.biz",
    "phone": "3695382906",
    "color": "Blue"
  },
  {
    "level": "debug",
    "ts": 1709652351.6065476,
    "caller": "logs-generator/logs-generator.go:47",
    "msg": "If we compress the protocol, we can get to the HDD circuit through the 1080p JSON port!",
    "name": "Kamron Marvin",
    "email": "janispfannerstill@sauer.io",
    "phone": "4465694677",
    "color": "Green"
  },
```

you can see, it's different log level, different color, etc... Now I want to configure this [filterprocessor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/filterprocessor/README.md) so some kind of logs will be dropped. For example logs with the level `error` and `debug`:

I tried the following:

```yaml
  opentelemetry-agent:
    config:
      exporters:
        debug:
          verbosity: detailed
      processors:
        filter/ottl:
          error_mode: ignore
          logs:
            log_record:
              - 'IsMatch(body["level"], "debug")'
              - 'IsMatch(body["level"], "error")'
      service:
        pipelines:
          logs:
            exporters:
              - debug
            processors:
              - filter/ottl
              - k8sattributes
              - resourcedetection/env
              - resourcedetection/region
              - batch
```

It doesn't work, I still can see these logs comes to Coralogix. I tried multiple options but nothing works.

You can see that I used here [debug exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/exporter/debugexporter/README.md) trying to figure out what need to be filtered, it didn't help me, you can see example output from debug here:

```json
{
  "level": "info",
  "ts": 1709665690.10114,
  "msg": {
    "ResourceLog #0": {
      "Resource SchemaURL": "https://opentelemetry.io/schemas/1.6.1",
      "Resource attributes": {
        "-> k8s.container.name": "Str(dummylogs)",
        "-> k8s.namespace.name": "Str(default)",
        "-> k8s.pod.name": "Str(dummylogs-58f59cf6c8-mtn7q)",
        "-> k8s.container.restart_count": "Str(0)",
        "-> k8s.pod.uid": "Str(2b42cdfc-05bf-4004-bca5-a5f74cb899e3)",
        "-> k8s.cluster.name": "Str(coralogix-dummylogs-2)",
        "-> cx.otel_integration.name": "Str(coralogix-integration-helm)",
        "-> k8s.deployment.name": "Str(dummylogs)",
        "-> k8s.node.name": "Str(coralogix-dummylogs-2)",
        "-> host.name": "Str(coralogix-dummylogs-2)",
        "-> os.type": "Str(linux)",
        "-> host.id": "Str(61419f744ec9452499a59356fc030992)"
      }
    },
    "ScopeLogs #0": {
      "ScopeLogs SchemaURL": "InstrumentationScope",
      "LogRecord #0": {
        "ObservedTimestamp": "2024-03-05 19:08:09.996222879 +0000 UTC",
        "Timestamp": "2024-03-05 19:08:09.845494796 +0000 UTC",
        "SeverityText": "",
        "SeverityNumber": "Unspecified(0)",
        "Body": "Str({\"level\":\"error\",\"ts\":1709665689.8447518,\"caller\":\"logs-generator/logs-generator.go:60\",\"msg\":\"Those Meeting Dig.\",\"error\":\"error\",\"stacktrace\":\"anatoly.dev/dummy-logs/internal/logs-generator.(*LogsGenerator).GenerateRandomErrorLog\\n\\t/app/internal/logs-generator/logs-generator.go:60\\nanatoly.dev/dummy-logs/internal/logs-generator.(*LogsGenerator).GenerateRandomLog\\n\\t/app/internal/logs-generator/logs-generator.go:71\\nanatoly.dev/dummy-logs/cmd.NewRootCommand.NewStartCommand.func1\\n\\t/app/cmd/start.go:38\\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute\\n\\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:983\\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC\\n\\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1115\\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute\\n\\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1039\\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteContext\\n\\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1032\\nmain.main\\n\\t/app/main.go:14\\nruntime.main\\n\\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:271\"})",
        "Attributes": {
          "-> log.file.path": "Str(/var/log/pods/default_dummylogs-58f59cf6c8-mtn7q_2b42cdfc-05bf-4004-bca5-a5f74cb899e3/dummylogs/0.log)",
          "-> time": "Str(2024-03-05T19:08:09.845494796Z)",
          "-> log.iostream": "Str(stderr)",
          "Trace ID": "",
          "Span ID": "",
          "Flags": "0"
        },
        "kind": "exporter",
        "data_type": "logs",
        "name": "debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```json
{
  "level": "info",
  "ts": 1709665689.2971187,
  "msg": {
    "ResourceLog #0": {
      "Resource SchemaURL": "https://opentelemetry.io/schemas/1.6.1",
      "Resource attributes": {
        "-> k8s.container.restart_count": "Str(0)",
        "-> k8s.pod.uid": "Str(2b42cdfc-05bf-4004-bca5-a5f74cb899e3)",
        "-> k8s.container.name": "Str(dummylogs)",
        "-> k8s.namespace.name": "Str(default)",
        "-> k8s.pod.name": "Str(dummylogs-58f59cf6c8-mtn7q)",
        "-> k8s.cluster.name": "Str(coralogix-dummylogs-2)",
        "-> cx.otel_integration.name": "Str(coralogix-integration-helm)",
        "-> k8s.deployment.name": "Str(dummylogs)",
        "-> k8s.node.name": "Str(coralogix-dummylogs-2)",
        "-> host.name": "Str(coralogix-dummylogs-2)",
        "-> os.type": "Str(linux)",
        "-> host.id": "Str(61419f744ec9452499a59356fc030992)"
      }
    },
    "ScopeLogs #0": {
      "ScopeLogs SchemaURL": "InstrumentationScope",
      "LogRecord #0": {
        "ObservedTimestamp": "2024-03-05 19:08:08.995622545 +0000 UTC",
        "Timestamp": "2024-03-05 19:08:08.84215517 +0000 UTC",
        "SeverityText": "",
        "SeverityNumber": "Unspecified(0)",
        "Body": "Str({\"level\":\"debug\",\"ts\":1709665688.8411458,\"caller\":\"logs-generator/logs-generator.go:47\",\"msg\":\"I'll bundle the haptic ADP bandwidth, that should construct the PCI circuit!\",\"name\":\"Laurianne Aufderhar\",\"email\":\"meganeschowalter@bartell.net\",\"phone\":\"2654965339\",\"color\":\"Green\"})",
        "Attributes": {
          "-> log.file.path": "Str(/var/log/pods/default_dummylogs-58f59cf6c8-mtn7q_2b42cdfc-05bf-4004-bca5-a5f74cb899e3/dummylogs/0.log)",
          "-> log.iostream": "Str(stderr)",
          "-> time": "Str(2024-03-05T19:08:08.84215517Z)",
          "Trace ID": "",
          "Span ID": "",
          "Flags": "0"
        },
        "kind": "exporter",
        "data_type": "logs",
        "name": "debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, my question is how can I define filterprocessor using [OTTL language](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/pkg/ottl/README.md) to filter logs based on:

1. level, i.e. error, debug info
2. based on `k8s.node.name` and level together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an OTEL expert or anything, and I never wrote a OTEL agent configuration from scratch, but it seems like you're trying to filter a field that is a string, but your filter expression treats it like a JSON object

I'm guessing this expression should work roughly

```
'IsMatch(ParseJSON(body)["level"], "debug")'
```